# I get Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean when running my code

Tags: java, selenium

This is the part where I get the error on, specifically on "for (int i = 0; i &lt; 5; i++) {"

This is the full code I'm using: http://www.seleniumtests.com/2011/08/verify-email-confirmation-using.html
Thanks ahead

```
for (int i = 0; i &amp;lt; 5; i++) {
            messages = folder.search(new SubjectTerm(
                    "Welcome to "),
                    folder.getMessages());
            //Wait for 10 seconds
            if (messages.length == 0) {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
        }
```

Comment: There are plenty of problems here, but if that's actually the error you're getting, maybe it's because `i &amp` is a bitwise AND which returns a number, but the test expression in a for header (after the first semicolon) should be a boolean. Seems like the compiler would have to be pretty lax or eager to report like that, though.  Your code *should* be `for (int i=0; i<5; i++ ) { … }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text

```
for (int i = 0; i &amp;lt; 5; i++) {
```

is a typo, probably produced by a broken text editor.  It should be this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

that's one mistake.